# how to change the default route in nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I am using `nopCommerce`, I want to change my default route from **Index** to another `ActionResult` **Promotion** which is also present in same `HomeController`, I have done these following tricks, but no solution,

in Nop.Web\Infrastructure\RouteProvider.cs

```
 //home page
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                            "",
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
            //for promotion
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Promotion",
                            "",
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Promotion" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

in Global.asax

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Promotion", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // changed to Promotion
                new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: Comment default route

Comment: @Div Exception: `No route in the route table matches the supplied values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by just adding value Home as url name in default route, I wounder I changed the Action as Index in Global.asax. This works fine.

```
//home page
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("HomePage",
                            "Home", // added value in the default route
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
            //for promotion
            routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Promotion",
                            "",
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Promotion" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```